# Firebase: How to verify Google login token id from Android & iOS

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-signin

I want to verify on my node backend all the tokens (Google login) i get from my Android app. I started with initializing the firebase module like this:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('googlefirebase');
admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
   databaseURL: url
});
```

This gave me some error about some DEFAULT name and i found out that i needed to use this code:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('googlefirebase');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

Then i realize that i need to install and init the project on my server so i did this:

```
firebase login
firebase init
firebase use --add project
firebase functions:config:set "google-services.json" (just the project_info data of the json that i downloaded from firebase)
```

Now i get this error:

> Error: Must initialize app with a cert credential or set your Firebase
>   project ID as the GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT environment variable to call
>   verifyIdToken()

EDIT START
I get this error when i call:

```
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token).then(function(decodedToken) {}.catch(){};
```

EDIT END

I already "init" firebase (or at least i thing so) and created the environment variables: GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT and FIREBASE_CONFIG and i keep getting the same error.

So, whats the right way to get firebase to work? what am i missing? is verifyIdToken the right method to verify the token? i just want to verify the google login token.

Answer (score 1):

With Cloud Functions for Firebase, you're not supposed to initialize like this any more:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

You're supposed to use no arguments:

```
admin.initializeApp();
```

Also, your google-services.json file is not useful in Cloud Functions.  That's only for use in an Android app.

Comment: Then how do i tell firebase in wich project i am wotking on? can you see my edit?

Comment: The project name is taken from the environment, which is automatically populated to be correct for you.  Look at any of the official samples that use the Admin SDK - they all init with no args (unless in some cases a special config is needed), and the documentation confirms this.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a FIREBASE_CONFIG environments variable and then call

```
// Initialize the default app
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var app = admin.initializeApp();
```

that config variable contain the initialize information like :

```
      databaseURL: 'https://databaseName.firebaseio.com',
     storageBucket: 'projectId.appspot.com',
     projectId: 'projectId'
```

Comment: Actually my FIREBASE_CONFIG variable has the path where the .json with all of that information is located

Comment: FIREBASE_CONFIG is set in Cloud Functions automatically.